# subprocess.Popen for loop output

Tags: python, subprocess

Code:

```
with open ('Client.txt','r') as Client_Name:  
    for Client in Client_Name:  
        out = subprocess.Popen(['script.sh', '-byclient', Client], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)   
        outputstring = out.communicate()  
        print (outputstring)
```

This code doesn't give the output, I want to pass the client names in `Client.txt` file to `script.sh`. Any suggestions please.

Answer (score -1):

Your code to pass the name to the script seems correct, but `communicate` actually returns a `tuple`, `(stdout_data, stderr_data)`.

You probably also want to pass `universal_newlines=True` to `Popen` to decode the output. Try this:

```
out = subprocess.Popen(['script.sh', '-byclient', Client],
                       stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                       universal_newlines=True)
out.wait()  # wait until the script has finished
stdout_data, stderr_data = out.communicate()
print(stdout_data)
```

Or, if you want to print the output in real time:

```
out = subprocess.Popen(['script.sh', '-byclient', Client],
                       stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                       universal_newlines=True)
for line in out.stdout:
    print(line)
```

Comment: with open ('Client.txt','r') as Client_Name:
 for Client in Client_Name:
  Policy_Detail = subprocess.Popen(['script.sh', '-byclient', Client], stdout=subprocess.PIPE,universal_newlines=True)
  Policy_Detail.wait()
  stdout_data, stderr_data = Policy_Detail.communicate()
  print(stdout_data)

Comment: Any suggest if I am passing the Client name in loop ?